# How to get for a given pixel the values from different overlapped rasters?

Tags: qgis, raster, features

I have a few rasters representing different soil properties, like soil pH and sand content.
The rasters overlap perfectly, have the same dimensions and same coordinate reference system.

I would like to be able to click on any pixel of my map and get the pH and sand values for this location. The "Identify Features" tool seems to return only the value of the selected raster, pH or Sand. It doesn't give the values of each rasters displayed. Are they any equivalent of the "Identify Features" tool that work on multiple rasters?

I am QGIS 2.2.0 user on a Windows computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Identify Features" tool will do just fine. You only need to adjust its settings like this:

- Set 'View' to 'Table'
- Set 'Mode' to 'Top down'

The picture below demonstrates the result for this identification for 3 rasters with several bands.

P.S. Screenshot is from QGIS 2.4. I don't remember if in QGIS 2.2 these options were inside this window or in 'Settings' -> 'Options'...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use gdalbuildvrt http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html and combine all your separate rasters into one multiband .vrt file. Add vrt into QGIS and hope that the Identify tool reports info about every band. Alternatively you can use gdallocationinfo http://www.gdal.org/gdallocationinfo.html.